# Is array index rebalanced after using unset in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to remove duplicates from a set of tokens using unset (not considering array_unique for now), however I am getting a few issues.

```
$keywords = parseTweet ( $tweet );
$term_freq = array(count($keywords));

for($i = 0; $i < count($keywords); $i++){
    $term_freq[$i] = 1;
    for($j = 0; $j < count($keywords); $j++){
        if (($i != $j) && (strcmp($keywords[$i],$keywords[$j]) == 0)){
            unset ( $keywords [$j] );
            unset ( $term_freq [$j] );          
            $term_freq[$i]++; 
        }
    }
}

print_r ( $keywords );
print_r ( $term_freq );
```

I am aware of why I am getting an error; while the duplicate $j is removed, the for loop still has to reloop for the rest of the keywords and hence will fail when it encounters the *missing* $j. Checking the contents of the array, I found out that the index of the array skips the index $j. So it reads; [1], [2], [4], ... etc where $j = [3]

I thought that unset also rebalances the array index, am I doing something wrong or missing something completely? I am new to PHP so please bear with me!

Comment: This doesn't makes sense: `unset ( $term_freq [$j] ); $term_freq[$j]++; ` you unset it and want to increase it?

Comment: Why are you initialzing the first element of `$term_freq` with `count($keywords)`? the first iteration of the `for` loop is going to overwrite this.

Comment: If you use `foreach` instead of `for`, it will just see the elements that still exist.

Comment: @Rizier123 Mistakenly referred to the deleted element rather than the intended one!

Comment: @Barmar Unfortunately I made a very short-sighted assumption and wrongly thought that I actually initiated the size of the array and not the first element.

Comment: You can use `array_fill` to create an array with a given number of elements. But why do you need to initialize the size of the array?

Comment: Well originally I intended to initialize it according to the number of keywords simply because I was unaware that 'array_fill' existed, but I will use that instead, thank you, I am still getting used to PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check if the index is set or not.
2. You're making needless, repetitive comparisons. Basically n² comparisons when at most n²/2 are required to compare every value in an array to every other value.

So:

```
$c = count($keywords)
for($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++){
    $term_freq[$i] = 1;
    for($j = $i+1; $j < $c; $j++){ // magic is $j = $i+1
        if( ! isset($keywords[$j]) { continue; } // skip unset indices
        else if ( strcmp($keywords[$i],$keywords[$j]) == 0 ){
            unset ( $keywords [$j] );
            unset ( $term_freq [$j] );          
            $term_freq[$i]++; 
        }
    }
}
```

Basically you *know* you've already checked everything prior to `$i`, so you can start your inner loop at `$i+1` instead of zero.

Also, you only need to count `$keywords` *once*, not n² times.

Comment: @cHao corrected. Re-considering it, this method will *still* scale quite terribly. It would be better to sort the array [with an efficient algo] and then walk over it to count/eliminate duplicate neighbours.

Comment: Might be better to just use `array_count_values` or `array_unique`, if i'm understanding the goal of the original code.  But that's on them.  :)

Comment: I ended up using 'array_count_values' instead, thanks a lot. I really need to get used to all these little predefined functions that php already has available. I imagine that these kind of predefined functions are fully optimized and it's no use making your own, right?

Answer (score 2):

Use `foreach` instead of `for`.

```
foreach ($keywords as $i => $kw1){
    $term_freq[$i] = 1;
    foreach ($keywords as $j => $kw2){
        if (($i != $j) && ($kw1 == $kw2){
            unset ( $keywords [$j] );
            unset ( $term_freq [$j] );          
            $term_freq[$i]++; 
        }
    }
}
```